# Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, overloading

I have error in above code please help me to solve the above error.

```
19/4     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the
         following:
         if
         The symbol "if" was substituted for ";" to continue.

20/10    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
         one of the following:
         begin end function pragma procedure
```

The code is :-

```
create or replace package body demo1 is
procedure max(a number , b number) as
    begin
        if a>b then
            DBMS _ output . put _ line('A Is Max..!');
        else
            DBMS _ output . put _ line('B Is Max..!');
        end if;
    end;
procedure max(a number , b number , c number) as
    begin
        if a>b and a>c then
            DBMS _ output . put _ line('A Is Max..!');
        else if b>c then
            DBMS _ output . put _ line('B Is Max..!');
        else
            DBMS _ output . put _ line('C Is Max..!');
        end if;
    end;
end demo1;
/
```

Please Any Help To Solve Above Error..!

Comment: You have two `if`s and one `end if`. Use `elsif` instead of `else if`

Answer (score 1):

Two errors: one is `ELSE IF` instead of `ELSIF` (as @astentx commented), and another is your *strange* way of writing `dbms_output.put_line`; although you *can* have spaces around the dot, you can't have it around the underline character. I'd suggest:

```
No : DBMS _ output . put _ line
Yes: dbms_output.put_line
```

Once fixed:

Package specification:

```
SQL> create or replace package demo1 is
  2  procedure max(a number , b number) ;
  3  procedure max(a number , b number , c number) ;
  4  end;
  5  /

Package created.
```

Package body:

```
SQL> create or replace package body demo1 is
  2  procedure max(a number , b number) as
  3      begin
  4          if a>b then
  5              DBMS_output . put_line('A Is Max..!');
  6          else
  7              DBMS_output . put_line('B Is Max..!');
  8          end if;
  9      end;
 10
 11  procedure max(a number , b number , c number) as
 12      begin
 13          if a>b and a>c then
 14              DBMS_output . put_line('A Is Max..!');
 15          elsif b>c then                                 --> ELSIF here, not ELSE IF
 16              DBMS_output . put_line('B Is Max..!');
 17          else
 18              DBMS_output . put_line('C Is Max..!');
 19          end if;
 20      end;
 21  end demo1;
 22  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```